# Can I prove equality of maps in fundamental group by identity?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading Munkres' chapter on Fundamental Group and working on this problem$^{(1)}$:

> Let $x_0, x_1$ be the two points of a path-connected space $X$. Pvove that $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is abelian iff for every pair $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of paths from the two points, we have $\hat{\alpha} = \hat{\beta}$.

By this posting I am not asking for solution to this question, because Munkres' is *the* textbook of Topology and this problem is so classic that I do not have shortage of solutions published online, such as [*here*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/topology/munkres.pdf), *[here](http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~leejunho/Problem2.pdf)* and *[here](http://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/131_spring_03/HW/Solutions-9.pdf)* and also *[here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/algebraic_topology/Math205B_Jan12.pdf)*! Duh! I am posting this just wanting to clarify my steps.

Let assume that I write the following when solving the problem:

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $f$ is a loop, $f \in \pi_1(X, x_0).$ Thus

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\alpha}([f]) &= [\bar{\alpha]} * [f] * [\alpha]\\
&= [\bar{\alpha]} * [\alpha] * [f] \\
&= [e_{x_0}] * [f]\\
&= [f], \\
\end{align}$$

implying that $\hat{\alpha}$ is an identity map. By similar argument, I can also finally go through that $\hat{\beta}([f]) = [f]$, implying again that $\hat{\beta}$ is an identity map. Thus $\hat{\alpha} = \hat{\beta}$ as desired.

Is there anything wrong with the steps above? Looks like they are "too short to be true," David-beats-Goliath does happen from time to time, but mostly it takes a special David. Thanks for your time and help.

---

(1) James Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd. ed., page 335, $\S 53$, exercise 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\hat{\alpha}([f]) &= [\bar{\alpha]} * [f] * [\alpha]\\
&= [\bar{\alpha]} * [\alpha] * [f] \\
&= [e_{x_0}] * [f]\\
&= [f], \\
\end{align} this step is not valid... because $\alpha $ may not be a loop based at $x_0$ ... abelian  fundamental group means $f*g =g*f$ where $f,g \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$...but here that  may not occur...

Comment: Thanks! I stand to be corrected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question for the opposite.
So suppose that $\hat{\alpha}=\hat{\beta}$ can we put ${\alpha}=f$ and ${\beta}=f*g$?, and f, g loops based on $x_0$.

I think that this is invalid since we want ${\alpha}, {\beta}$ to be paths from $x_0$ to $x_1$